# Adding members to PSCustomObject variable - understanding what's going on

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get my head around what is going on here, and I was wondering if anyone knew of a resource that might point me in the right direction, or could explain it a bit for me.

I am trying to create a PSCustomObject variable, and then members to it, like this:

```
$myObject += [PSCustomObject]@{
    FirstName = 'Bill'
    LastName = 'Bobbins'
    Age    = '30'
}

$myObject += [PSCustomObject]@{
    FirstName = 'Ben'
    LastName = 'Bobbins'
    Age    = '40'
}
```

So the first bit of code executes fine, but the second bit results in an error "Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'." Also, if I pipe $myObject to get-member, I can see that $myObject is TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject.

Now, if I set $myObject to be an empty array first, and then try to add members, I am successful. This code works without error:

```
$myObject=@()

$myObject += [PSCustomObject]@{
    FirstName = 'Bill'
    LastName = 'Bobbins'
    Age    = '30'
}

$myObject += [PSCustomObject]@{
    FirstName = 'Ben'
    LastName = 'Bobbins'
    Age    = '40'
}
```

If I now pipe $myObject to get-member, I still get TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject. So my question is, why am I allowed to add multiple members to $myObject in the second example, but not in the first, when the data type is the same for both examples?

Any help is muchly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Your second code produces one array with two objects in it, which is not at all the same thing as adding members to an object. Your first code simply produces a single custom object because, when `$myObject` is not initialized, it is effectively treated as `$null`, and PowerShell allows `$null` to be added to just about anything as an identity element (to make scripting easier). But that single custom object obviously does not support addition on its own.

Comment: as an addition use '$myObject.GetType()' to see what type your variable is

Comment: `$myObject[0] | get-member` would give you the members you need. As Jeroen said, you have an array, not an element.

Comment: Thanks all! I think that one of the things that I need to brush up on is using the correct words. I appreciate the input and it gives me something to look up and understand properly - so thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is with how `Get-Member`/the pipeline works - it's tripped me up before!

This will unroll the array, and give you the type of **each element** as it passes it across the pipeline:

```
$myObject | Get-Member
```

This will pass the **whole object**, and correctly give you the type as `System.Object[]`

```
 Get-Member -InputObject $myObject
```

You can test this out by for example adding `$myObject += "test string"` to the end of your code and trying to get members both ways. The first will return both `PSObject` and `String` types.

Sidepoint: The `$myObject = @()` line can be avoided by specifying you are creating an array the first time you declare `$myObject`. Example:

```
[array]$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{

[PSCustomObject[]]$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
```

Comment: Thanks gms0ulman - very useful! Every day is a school day - many thanks